# Are multiple async file appends on the same file safe?

Tags: node.js, append, fs

Looking at the pseudo-code below, is it possible for the writes to the file to become mangled?

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
  fs.appendFile("myfile.txt", "myline"+i+'\n', somecallback)
```

fs is [found here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Possibility I'd expect:

```
myline3
myline4
myline1
myline2
myline0
```

But would this be possible?

```
mylimyline4
ne3
myline1
myline2
myline0
```

In which case the second append would have occurred in the middle of the first. Because if this can happen I'll have to queue the writes manually.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a programm to test that and was unable to make it mix different appends.

```
var fs = require('fs')

var filename = __dirname + '/file.bin'
var bytes_per_buff = parseInt(process.argv[2]) || 4096
var num_buffs = parseInt(process.argv[3]) || 256
var buffs = []

for (var i=0; i<num_buffs; i++) {
    buffs[i] = new Buffer(bytes_per_buff)
    for (var j=0; j<bytes_per_buff; j++) {
        buffs[i][j] = i
    }
}

fs.writeFile(filename, '', ()=>console.log('file created'))
for (var i=0; i<num_buffs; i++) {
    (function(buff_num) { //closure to log buff_num
        fs.appendFile(filename, buffs[buff_num], ()=>console.log(buff_num))
    }(i))
}
```